Page source not showing any prismic slices's html
I'm using prismic and next.js to create a website. Everything works fine. During optimizing SEO, when I view page source, it does not contain the html of any prismic slice and there are no headings or body tags etc in the page source. Here is my code for one page (homepage)
`import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { SliceZone } from "@prismicio/react";

import { createClient } from "~/prismicio";
import { components } from "~/slices/marketing";

export default async function Page() {
  const client = createClient();
  const page = await client.getSingle("home_page");

  return <SliceZone slices={page.data.slices} components={components} />;
}

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  const client = createClient();
  const page = await client.getSingle("home_page");

  return {
    keywords: page.data.keywords,
    openGraph: {
      siteName: "Zolvecare",
      title: page.data.meta_title!,
      description: page.data.meta_description!,
      images: [
        {
          url: page.data.meta_image.url!,
          width: page.data.meta_image.dimensions?.width,
          height: page.data.meta_image.dimensions?.height,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
}


I wasn't able to figure out this

Assuming you can visually see everything your page, you may be viewing the development version of the page's HTML. The output is slightly different than the production version. Both versions should include all of the page's HTML, but it should be more obvious in the production version. Try running next build and next start to inspect the HTML. Lastly, if your slices only render on the client for whatever reason (unlikely), it will not be included in the server-side HTML.

The live version also shows the same

Maybe check the id of the Page Type, it might be homepage instead of home_page depending on your setup. You can check in the index.json file of the Page Type in your code.
